# Having a really weird OutOf Memory error in my app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have read pretty much all the related problems on stackoverflow but non seem to relate to the problem that I have.  First of all, my app containts 160 plus images of approx. 180 - 300KB each with dimensions of 800 x 2000. Now on my samsung galaxy s2 (version 4.0.3) my app works fine no problems (testing it for about 20 minutes at a time) and on my galaxy young (version 2.3.6) still works like a charm (testing it in the same way)  However, on my motorola xoom 2 tablet 10.1 inch(version4.0.4) not even 2 minutes in of testing the app it gives me java.lang.OutOfMemory error.  Now on some threads ive read java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget, but this doesn't relate to me as I am just getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Here is the errors i am getting.

```
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream  (BitmapFactory.java:520)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:783)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1954)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:666)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:570)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:343)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at com.example.sample.app.Samples$5.onClick(Samples.java:77)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3526)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run    (View.java:14149)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:605)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:92)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4697)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-11 10:00:33.266: E/AndroidRuntime(5390):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have asked my friend to test the app on his samsung tablet 10.1 inch (not sure of his version) to see if the same issue crops up. Havent heard from him yet, but once I do I will post here what the results are. So if he doesn't get a error can I safely assume that it is my tablet? or does my app not work properly on tablets?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need to keep all these Bitmaps in memory at a time?

Comment: Um sorry what do you mean keeping the Bitmaps in memory? if i can get rid of them then great, but how?

Comment: Every time you create a Bitmap, you load the image contents into memory. Memory heap per application in Android is quite limited, so you'll want to optimize the Bitmap usage in your application. Make sure you load only those Bitmaps that are needed by your application at the current moment and recycle() those that aren't needed anymore.

Comment: If your android version is later then 3.0 you can extend the heap size. I am not 100% sure how, but it is made possible by the android API.

Comment: Well what I have done is that I have an imageview, and have 42 buttons each with a sample image. when selecting the button it displays the image. heres and example. final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iM2);
        slider.animateOpen();
        
        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.samplea); next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.samplea); and so it goes for all other buttons and images

Comment: Extend the heap size in eclipse?

Comment: Hi all I think I have found the solution. It seems to be working, but will see when i have added the rest of the images to my app. the solution i found was adding the android:largeHeap="true" in manifest file by <applications>. Holding thumbs now to see if it will still work.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a workaround what you find. It won't run on low memory devices.
You have do reduce the size of your images to use less memory.

It's a well known problem in android, so google a little, and you find a lot of thread explaining how to deal with bitmaps in Android